# How to combine Knn with boost?

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say my index contains 3 fields.

```
PUT my-image-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
       "image-vector": {
        "type": "dense_vector",
        "dims": 3,
        "index": true,
        "similarity": "l2_norm"
      },
      "file-type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I query it using the *knn* options:

```
POST my-image-index/_search
{
  "size" : 3,
  "query" : {
    "knn": {
      "field": "image-vector",
      "query_vector": [-5, 9, -12],
      "num_candidates": 10
    }
  }
}
```

How can I apply a boost that refers to a field in my index? e.g. all documents with *file-type=pdf* get a boost of 0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
POST image-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "file-type": {
        "query": "pdf",
        "boost": 0.9
      }
    }
  },
  "knn": {
    "field": "image-vector",
    "query_vector": [54, 10, -2],
    "k": 5,
    "num_candidates": 50,
    "boost": 0.1
  },
  "size": 10
}
```

Doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/knn-search.html#_combine_approximate_knn_with_other_features